# systemd service status is in activating state all the time

Tags: systemd, rhel, systemctl

I am running into a problem with systemd service, status of the script is always in "Activating state" not in "active". I am not sure what is the problem. Please help me on this.

I have created systemd service which will execute a bash script for every 30 seconds

```
My script : 
#!/bin/bash
PGPORT=$1
echo "running through bash script thourgh  systemd working `date`" >> //tmp/diditwork.txt
```

My systemd service configuration

```
[root@pglinux02 system]# cat /etc/systemd/system/test-pg.service
[Unit]
Description=PostgreSQL db Service
After=network.target

[Service]
User=postgres
Type=simple
ExecStart=/tmp/test.sh 5432
Restart=always
RestartSec=30
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
[root@pglinux02 system]#
```

my script is executing as expected, but when I check the status of the service, it is showing "activating" state all the time

```
[root@pglinux02 system]# systemctl status test-pg.service
● test-pg.service - PostgreSQL db Service 
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/test-pg.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: **activating (auto-restart)** since Fri 2021-10-29 19:49:57 GMT; 6s ago
  Process: 5274 ExecStart=/tmp/test.sh 5432 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 5274 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
[root@pglinux02 system]#
```

what is the way to make this service "Active (running)" ?
if Add another parameter "RemainAfterExit=yes" , script is running 1st time, and it is not running in subsequent interval

please advise on my mistake along with the solution

Thank you
Durga

Comment: Without reproducing it here, I suspect it's because of the `Type=simple`; systemd sees the bash instance start and considers it active, but that shell exits shortly afterwards. What is systemd supposed to think? The process that it started is now gone. It's probably trying to restart it every 30 seconds. Maybe add a `sleep inf` at the end of the script to simulate being active??

Comment: The correct way to do what @JeffSchaller suggests is to set `Type=oneshot` and `RemainAfterExit=yes`, but I assume since the description is “PostgreSQL db Service”, the thing you really want is to actually launch the postgress process in your script and wait for it to exit before exiting the script.